# Jboss 7.0.1 : Started 122 of 176 services (54 services are passive or on-demand)

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I deployed my war file in Jboss AS 7.0.1 successfully after I run the following command;

```
/host=master/server-config=mobile:start
```

I get the following;

```
[Server:mobile] 12:47:50,349 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) Removing bootstrap log handlers
[Server:mobile] 12:47:50,391 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ee] (Controller Boot Thread) Activating EE subsystem
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting deployment of "MobileGateway.war"
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,515 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) added javax.persistence.api dependency to MobileGateway.war
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,809 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-4) registering web context: /MobileGateway
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,822 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) Deployed "MobileGateway.war"
[Server:mobile] 12:47:51,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBoss AS 7.0.1.Final "Zap" started in 4692ms - Started 122 of 176 services (54 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Everything looks fine until you start looking at the last line which says Started 122 of 176 services. What happened to the other 54 services? Why isn't the server starting the rest of the services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JBoss AS 7 starts some services lazily. This means they aren't all started when you startup (and thus taking precious startup time), when they perhaps are never needed.

E.g. when you don't use the timer service in any of your beans, it doesn't need to be started. When you never use JSF, there is no need to do its initialization, etc.

This is the same approach taken by Glassfish, and is one of the things why is starts up so fast.

Comment: But the explanation you just gave me does'nt have any thing to do with this :
Not Found
The requested URL /MobileGateway/ was not found on this server.
when I just try to open it in the browser..

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Perhaps it's better to open a new question for that?

Comment: I agree with Arjan, this is another question, and one that you will need to specify the Interface and Port settings being exposed by your application. Also, it would help to know A) your expected results, B) your process, and C) your results. In that order, we can better help address one question as a time, and it really helps the community who will come across this in the future. Great questions though!

Comment: Thanks for all the replies... I just figured the next portion by self...
Though the information that Arjan posted here was useful in the scenario that I was looking into.. :)